# What went wrong: app freezes on some devices?

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

i have been developing an app and there has been a problem of performance in some devices like with same configuration but brand difference.
i am using two devices lenovo and samsung. with same processors same RAM same ROM.
The app is behaving differently on both devices on samsung it hangs and on lenovo it works fine.
is there anything wrong with my code or i anyone else has faced same problem and found any solution to it?

//volley request

```
 private void request() {
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url + "abc.php",
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            systemm.out("Daily Dose"+response);
                            try {
                                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);
                                int count = jArray.length();
                                for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
                                    JSONObject j = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                    Item itemm=new Item();
                                    itemm.setUrlPic(j.getString("image"));
                                    itemm.setPicCount(j.getString("imcount"));
                                    itemm.setName(CapitalLetter.AllFirstLetterWithBlanckSpace(Basee64.Decode2(j.getString("fname"))+" "
                                            +Basee64.Decode2(j.getString("lname"))));
                                    itemm.setAbout(CapitalLetter.AllFirstLetterWithBlanckSpace(Basee64.Decode2(j.getString("fullabout"))));
                                    itemm.setAgeHeight(j.getString("age")+","
                                            +Basee64.Decode2(j.getString("height")));
                                    itemm.setMaritalStatus(Basee64.Decode2(j.getString("marital")));
                                    itemm.setReligion(Basee64.Decode2(j.getString("religion")));
                                    itemm.setEat(Basee64.Decode2(j.getString("food")));
                                    itemm.setDrink(Basee64.Decode2(j.getString("drink")));
                                    itemm.setSmoke(Basee64.Decode2(j.getString("smoke")));
                                    itemm.setLocation(CapitalLetter.FirstLetter(Basee64.Decode2(j.getString("city")))+","
                                            +CapitalLetter.FirstLetter(Basee64.Decode2(j.getString("state")))+","
                                            +CapitalLetter.FirstLetter(Basee64.Decode2(j.getString("country"))));
                                    itemm.setQualification(Basee64.Decode2(j.getString("education")));
                                    itemm.setAnnualIncome(Basee64.Decode2(j.getString("income")));
                                    items.add(itemm);
                                    show(page);
                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            systemm.out("Daily Dose"+error.getMessage());

                        }
                    }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("uid", "1");
                    return params;
                }

            };
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activityy);
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        }

        private void show(int i) {

            Item it=items.get(i);
            nameTv.setText(it.getName());
            aboutTv.setText(it.getAbout());
            age_height_Tv.setText(it.getAgeHeight());
            maritalStatusTv.setText(it.getMaritalStatus());
            religionTv.setText(it.getReligion());
            eatTv.setText(it.getEat());
            drinkTv.setText(it.getDrink());
            smokeTv.setText(it.getSmoke());
            locationTv.setText(it.getLocation());
            QualificationTv.setText(it.getQualification());
            AnnualIncomeTv.setText(it.getAnnualIncome());
            picCountTv.setText(it.getPicCount());

            //String urll="http://ste.india.com/sites/default/files/2015/12/18/442851-max.jpg";
            //String urll="http://www.fashioncentral.pk/images/models/111/Sanam_Jung_Pic.jpg";
            imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(activityy.getApplicationContext()).getImageLoader();
            imageLoader.get(Config.urlImage+it.getUrlPic(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(profilePicIv, R.drawable.blur, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));
            profilePicIv.setImageUrl(Config.urlImage+it.getUrlPic(), imageLoader);



        }
```

//custom volley

```
public class CustomVolleyRequest {

    private static CustomVolleyRequest customVolleyRequest;
    private static Context context;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;


    private CustomVolleyRequest(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.requestQueue = getRequestQueue();

        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQueue,
                new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                    private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                            cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

                    @Override
                    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                        return cache.get(url);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                        cache.put(url, bitmap);
                    }
                });
    }

    public static synchronized CustomVolleyRequest getInstance(Context context) {
        if (customVolleyRequest == null) {
            customVolleyRequest = new CustomVolleyRequest(context);
        }
        return customVolleyRequest;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (requestQueue == null) {
            Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(context.getCacheDir(), 10 * 1024 * 1024);
            Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
            requestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
            requestQueue.start();
        }
        return requestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return imageLoader;
    }

}
```

//capital letter

```
public class CapitalLetter {
    public static String AllFirstLetterWithBlanckSpace(String str) {
        String[] strArray = str.split(" ");
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String s : strArray) {
            String cap = s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1);
            builder.append(cap + " ");
        }


        return builder.toString();
    }


        public static String FirstLetter(String str) {
            String[] strArray = str.split(" ");
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (String s : strArray) {
                String cap = s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1);
                builder.append(cap + "");
            }


            return builder.toString();
        }

        public static String Peragrap(String str) {
            String[] strArray = str.split(".");
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (String s : strArray) {
                String cap = s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1);
                builder.append(cap + ".");
            }


            return builder.toString();
        }
    }
```

// base64 encode decode

```
public class Basee64 {


    public static String Decode(String s) {

        String data=null;
        if(s!=null) {
            try {
                data = new String(Base64.decode(s, Base64.DEFAULT), "UTF-8").trim();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return data;
    }

    public static String Encode(String s) {

        String data=null;

        if(s!=null) {
            try {
                data = Base64.encodeToString(s.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT).trim();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return data;
    }




     public static String Decode2(String s) {
            String data=null;
            if(s!=null) {
                try {
                    data = new String(Base64.decode(new String(Base64.decode(s, Base64.DEFAULT), "UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT), "UTF-8").trim();
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return data;
        }

        public static String Encode2(String s) {
            String data=null;

            if(s!=null) {
                try {
                    data = Base64.encodeToString(Base64.encodeToString(s.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT).trim().getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT).trim();
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return data;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you working with images? Post some code.

Comment: Yes.i am working with images and string.

Comment: Do you expect us to work through the code completely, just to spot some issue that shows *one some devices*? Have you been debugging the application of the device you've encountered the issues at? Have you isolated the statements that cause the hang?

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
        Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
```

where your code is getting stucked
becauase some phones didnt clear the RAM automatically but your app need more memory through this way you can assign more memory to your operation . To clear out memory use below

```
  System.runFinalization();
    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
    System.gc();
```

//to clear out memory

Comment: for images which library is you using?

Comment: i am using volley for images and tabhost and arrays to fetch data.

Comment: yeah its good to use volley but if you are using bitmaps n ol its gonna be memory n resource consuming use Glide or picasso to show images @de

Comment: @DEEPAKMITTAL can you use all these network in asynctasks that will free your main thread for doing such operations

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is great. But programming side , you have to do something more like threading, service handler. If you are coding all in main thread it will hang until the process to finish. But put the non-ui things to background thread, or async task.

Comment: so there is no need for thread service handler in volley right?

Answer (score 0):

If the app freezes long enough to get the Application Not Responding (ANR) popup, then you can pull the traces.txt file to see exactly what's going on:

`adb pull /data/anr/traces.txt`

That file will contain a thread dump of your application.  Look at what the main thread is doing.  That will be a hint as to what should be put on a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

How big is the response? Inflating json is not cheap, if your json is very big this means that the app can take some time to create the appropriate objects to represent your json. If that's the reason try to inflate the json using the JsonReader.